# Look up the panda bear

Tags: riddle, humor

A panda bear walked into a restaurant. He sat down at a table and ordered some food.

When he was finished eating, he took out a gun and shot his waiter. He then left the restaurant.

After the police caught up with him, they asked him why he had killed the waiter.

He replied, “Look me up in the dictionary.”

**What did the dictionary say?**

Comment: Hey, why the downvote?  It's not fair nor constructive to downvote without saying why.

Comment: this what people call a "situation" riddle. after many and long discussions they have been considered "off-topic". NB I did not DV

Comment: See: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120/situation-riddles AND: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46/so-whats-our-actual-stance-on-riddles

Comment: I looked through the FAQs for clues to how to use this site properly.  There's no way I would have found those threads unless I knew to look for them.  Maybe that exclusion should be in the FAQ.

Comment: @BGM Feel free to open a thread on Meta about it! It's very possible for us to edit it into the "do not ask" section. Though honestly, I think the reason this received downvotes is because it's not as much a riddle as it is a very common-knowledge pun.

Comment: @Emrakul  Okay.  Here is my start: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/can-we-add-some-clarifications-to-the-faq-or-help

Comment: This isn't actually a situation riddle, even though it sounds like one. The answer is a pun based on wordplay, and the story is setup for it.

Comment: @xnor I agree with you.  I wish I hadn't posted it.  But since this is a beta site, I'll not delete it so that we can retain the conversation piece.  Hopefully I won't lose a hundred points for the contribution.

Comment: @BGM Wait, I'm defending the riddle as *not* being a situation riddle, which someone people have claimed to be off-topic on Meta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a joke, not a puzzle.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Why can't jokes be puzzles? It's like the guy walks in the bar joke. That's still a puzzle.

Comment: I don't know a puzzle about a guy walking into a bar, @CyanogenCX. Puzzles can have humorous solutions, but a puzzle gives you gripping points that lead you to a conclusion: the solution. A joke is the opposite: it _mis_leads you, or leads you nowhere, so that the punchline has maximum comedic impact. I can't imagine anyone "solving" this without already having heard the story. It's too broad: nothing points to the specific wording of the solution, and exact wording is the key to having the correct answer.

Comment: Here's the meta for the difference between a joke and a riddle:  http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/whats-the-difference-between-a-riddle-and-a-joke

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Panda - Eats shoots and leaves