# A monkey, a squirrel, and a bird

Tags: riddle

A monkey, a squirrel, and a bird are racing to the top of a coconut tree. Who will get the banana first, the monkey, the squirrel, or the bird?

Comment: Monkey, because monkey has a "key" to the banana on a coconut tree!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple joke, not a puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That's a coconut tree - no bananas(unless you bring your own, in which case a monkey is more likely to carry a banana) and what you posted was supposed to be puzzling.

I can see a wave of downvotes soaring towards your question. `;-)`

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, what kind of "tags" should i add to this kind of question?

Comment: I'm not very "old" here either but soon enough a moderator may leave a link for you to read if this is not accepted as a riddle on this site. I predicted downvotes because I've seen that people on SE don't like easy puzzles/questions. You could see a somewhat similar example [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/look-up-the-panda-bear)

Comment: @Pierre I've taken the liberty of editing your tags. On this site at least, the "riddle" tag is mainly used for "what am I?"-type puzzles.